# express.js ejs not rendering my html

Tags: javascript, html, express, ejs, json2html

I'm using Express.js with EJS to render the response from a database query as an html unordered list. I'm also using [json2html](http://json2html.com/). I'm not getting any errors but my list item elements are not getting rendered as HTML. What am I doing wrong?

The page renders in my browser like this -

[image]

My Express router handler -

```
var $stmt = squel.select().from('GrpPractice').field('*').toString();

router.get('/', handler1);

function handler1(req, res) {
    db.all($stmt, function(err, rows) {
        var transform = {'tag':'li', 'html':'${Organization legal name}'};
        var html    = json2html.transform(rows, transform);
        res.render('index', { title: 'Group Practices', html });    
        //  res.send(rows);
        });
}
```

And my EJS template -

```
  <body>
    <h1><%= title %></h1>
    <p>Welcome to <%= title %></p>
    <ul>
        <%= html %> 
    </ul>
  </body>
```

My data appears well formed -

```
[{"Organization legal name":"23RD FAMILY MED LLC","Group Practice PAC ID":"3375715477","Number of Group Practice members":5,"First Name":"CHERL","Last Name":"MUES","Credential":"","Primary specialty":"NURSE PRACTITIONER"},{"Organization legal name":"23RD FAMILY MED LLC","Group Practice PAC ID":"3375715477","Number of Group Practice members":5,"First Name":"PAUL","Last Name":"GLOWACKI","Credential":"MD","Primary specialty":"FAMILY PRACTICE"},{"Organization legal name":"23RD FAMILY MED LLC","Group Practice PAC ID":"3375715477","Number of Group Practice members":5,"First Name":"MONTY","Last Name":"SELLON","Credential":"","Primary specialty":"FAMILY PRACTICE"},{"Organization legal name":"23RD FAMILY MED LLC","Group Practice PAC ID":"3375715477","Number of Group Practice members":5,"First Name":"MILO","Last Name":"ANDERSON","Credential":"","Primary specialty":"FAMILY PRACTICE"},{"Organization legal name":"23RD FAMILY MED LLC","Group Practice PAC ID":"3375715477","Number of Group Practice members":5,"First Name":"ANDREW","Last Name":"OPP","Credential":"","Primary specialty":"FAMILY PRACTICE"},{"Organization legal name":"3-D OPTICAL","Group Practice PAC ID":"1951361732","Number of Group Practice members":4,"First Name":"KRISTEN","Last Name":"KOSIR","Credential":"OD","Primary specialty":"OPTOMETRY"},{"Organization legal name":"3-D OPTICAL","Group Practice PAC ID":"1951361732","Number of Group Practice members":4,"First Name":"NIROPA","Last Name":"PRASAD","Credential":"","Primary specialty":"OPTOMETRY"},{"Organization legal name":"3-D OPTICAL","Group Practice PAC ID":"1951361732","Number of Group Practice members":4,"First Name":"ROBERT","Last Name":"MCCAMY","Credential":"OD","Primary specialty":"OPTOMETRY"},{"Organization legal name":"3-D OPTICAL","Group Practice PAC ID":"1951361732","Number of Group Practice members":4,"First Name":"DARREL","Last Name":"CRISSLER","Credential":"","Primary specialty":"OPTOMETRY"},{"Organization legal name":"5MD CONVENIENT CARE LLC","Group Practice PAC ID":"2567643026","Number of Group Practice members":4,"First Name":"JULIE","Last Name":"HATCH","Credential":"","Primary specialty":"NURSE PRACTITIONER"}]
```

If I log to console it looks like valid html

```
<li>23RD FAMILY MED LLC</li><li>23RD FAMILY MED LLC</li><li>23RD FAMILY MED LLC</li><li>23RD FAMILY MED LLC</li><li>23RD FAMILY MED LLC</li><li>3-D OPTICAL</li><li>3-D OPTICAL</li><li>3-D OPTICAL</li><li>3-D OPTICAL</li><li>5MD CONVENIENT CARE LLC</li>
```

If I view page source in the browser (thank you Tomasz Jakub Rup), not so valid...

```
 <body>
    <h1>Group Practices</h1>
    <p>Welcome to Group Practices</p>
    <ul>
        &lt;li&gt;23RD FAMILY MED LLC&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;23RD FAMILY MED LLC&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;23RD FAMILY MED LLC&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;23RD FAMILY MED LLC&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;23RD FAMILY MED LLC&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;3-D OPTICAL&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;3-D OPTICAL&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;3-D OPTICAL&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;3-D OPTICAL&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;5MD CONVENIENT CARE LLC&lt;/li&gt; 
    </ul>
  </body>
```

Can anyone identify what I'm doing wrong? It appears as if my browser is interpreting this as a text string, rather than markup.

Comment: Looks like You have in `index` template `<%- html %>` instead `<%= html %>`

Comment: It's definitely an equals (=) sign I have there. Thanks for looking tho...

Comment: look at page source. what content is? escaped or not?

Comment: Oh! My page source - " <body>
    <h1>Group Practices</h1>
    <p>Welcome to Group Practices</p>
    <ul>
        &lt;li&gt;23RD FAMILY MED LLC&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;23RD FAMILY MED LLC&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;23RD FAMILY MED LLC&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;23RD FAMILY MED LLC&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;23RD FAMILY MED LLC&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;3-D OPTICAL&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;3-D OPTICAL&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;3-D OPTICAL&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;3-D OPTICAL&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;5MD CONVENIENT CARE LLC&lt;/li&gt; 
    </ul>
  </body>"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `<%= html %>` with `<%- html %>`

[ejs](http://ejs.co/#docs) has less popular convention:

`<%=` produce escaped value

`<%-` produce unescaped value

[lodash.template](https://lodash.com/docs#template) has an inverse convention (more popular):

`<%-` produce escaped value

`<%=` produce unescaped value

Comment: Thank you Tomasz. I missed that in the documentation. I should learn to RTFM better.